# Event binding Ctrl-Shift-N in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using to jQuery.hotkeys to bind keyboard events.

I'm trying to bind <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>

```
$(document).bind('keydown', 'ctrl+shift+n', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('Ctrl+Shift+N');
    return false;
});
```

The above is not working. Any ideas?

Comment: Where did you read that you could pass 'ctrl+shift+n' to keydown?

Comment: It looks correct - your modifiers are in alphabetical order. Which browser are you using?

Comment: Juan, I based it off the jQuery hotkeys documentation. There's no mention however of 'ctrl-shift-#' just 'ctrl-#', 'shift-#'. Steve, I'm using Chrome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chrome doesn't let you take over some shortcuts.

If you use the following code http://jsfiddle.net/rNkmA/1/

```
$(document).bind('keydown', function(e) {
    console.log(e.which);
    console.log(e.ctrlKey);
    console.log(e.shiftKey);
    if (e.ctrlKey && e.shiftKey && e.which === 78) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log('Ctrl+Shift+N');
        return false;
    }
});​
```

You'll see that the handler never gets called in Chrome

I suggest you use a shortcut that is not preassigned to chrome like <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd>. That will work in FF, IE, Safari and Chrome (does anybody ever test for Opera?)